# Measuring Runtime - Not Precise Enough

Tags: c++, sorting, runtime, mergesort, c++-chrono

I've got an assignment here. The programming side of it should be relatively simple, but I can't seem to get results here. We are to implement merge sort and radix sort and then test them on groups of random numbers. Test it ten times for n = 10, n = 100, n = 1000, and n = 10000, averaging each of the ten tests to get an average runtime. Sounds simple enough, but I can't seem to get any results for n = 10, and the results for n = 100 and n = 1000 aren't very precise. The most I can get out of them is something like, .0001.

The point of the assignment is to compare these runtimes to the theoretical runtimes, but we've never discussed how to handle getting a runtime, so the most any of us can do is Google aimlessly in hopes of finding something that works.

I've tried a few different methods of doing this, and none of them have produced adequate results. The most recent attempt is by using chrono and the high_resolution_clock. Still no good. I even tried putting my computer under a stress test and running the program while at ~100% load and it still didn't work.

```
for(int cnt = 0; cnt < 10; cnt++)
{
    populate(numbers, 10);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    mergeSort(numbers,0,numbers.size()-1);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    dur += duration;
}

cout << endl << "For N = 10, Mergesort Average Runtime: " << dur/10;
dur = 0;
```

Comment: use `std::chrono::super_duper_high_resolution_clock` ;)

Comment: I'm surprised an instructor would expect you to get measurable numbers from values of `n` as low as 10, 100, or even 1000. I would have had you start with 10K or more.

Comment: I'm getting to that point. Haha

The only reason I don't just measure the entire for loop is that I'd be measuring the time to populate the vector each time, which would skew the results.

Comment: What do you get when you just do `std::chrono::duration<double>(t2 - t1).count();`

Comment: I changed them all to

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration<double>(t1 - t2).count();

and got some strange results:

For N = 10, Mergesort Average Runtime: 0
For N = 100, Mergesort Average Runtime: 0
For N = 1000, Mergesort Average Runtime: -0.0006
For N = 10000, Mergesort Average Runtime: -0.0036002

Am I time traveling?

Comment: It is `t2 - t1`, think about it ....  What is its randomness of the array ?

Comment: Whoops. I copied it wrong. It's been a long day. Still no better.  

For N = 10, Mergesort Average Runtime: 0
For N = 100, Mergesort Average Runtime: 0
For N = 1000, Mergesort Average Runtime: -0.0006
For N = 10000, Mergesort Average Runtime: -0.0036002

Comment: srand(time(NULL)); for the seed
(rand()*4)%100000;

Comment: Instead of trying to be more precise with the clock, try doing more work and divide by a greater factor. Precision will greatly increase.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to measure the time it takes to populate the array. So my only option is to make more arrays, populate them, and then do a bunch of sorts in a row. I've tried it with twenty arrays and still get nothing usable for n = 10 or n = 100. Simply changing the amount of iterations of the loop above wouldn't do anything since each individual measurement is showing as 0. I'd have to measure a bunch of them at once, which just gets messy when you're making more and more arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 10 loops on a single array, use 10 arrays (even 10 arrays of 10,000 won't be an issue for memory usage). Populate the 10 arrays with random numbers, then call mergesort() 10 times to sort each of the 10 arrays. This will help a bit. However, even this may not be enough. I did some testing with much larger arrays:

Time to sort 4,194,304 64 bit elements of psuedo random data:

```
radix sort     203 ms
merge sort     297 ms
```

64 bit mode, Windows XP64, Visual Studio 2005 compiler. Intel i7 2600K 3.4ghz, DP67BG motherboard, 4GB ram

You could use more arrays, but if the number of arrays is large, then the calling overhead becomes a factor. Radix sort is linear in time O(n), while merge sort is O(n log2(n)). You could test larger arrays, then use the formulas to estimate times for small arrays.

For a higher precision timer, you can get a cpu cycle count using the X86 rdtsc instruction (assembly) or an intrinsic if your compiler supports it. Since it's a cycle count, it's unaffected if the cpu has an automatic overclocking mode, such as Intel's turbo boost.

Comment: I've tried that. I even just brought it up to 20 arrays and I still don't get results for n = 10 or n = 100. I honestly wouldn't know where to begin with your X86 suggestion, and I'd wager that that's really a bit out of scope for this class. I'm just going to have to wait on the professor to get back to me and see what he has to say.

Comment: @Shoggoth269 while you're at it, to be *completely* "fair", each sample set of data should be *identical* in original random order when submitted to each algorithm. I.e., generate the data *once* (per sample size), make a backup copy, then for-each-algorithm (a) copy backup data to to-be-sorted array, then (b) sort the data. its the only way you're not rolling the dice on your prng with each change in algorithms.

Comment: @Shoggoth269 - Microsoft compiler intrinsic: [msdn rdtsc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twchhe95.aspx), GCC compiler example: [GCC rdtsc](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/How_To_Read_The_TSC_With_GCC.shtml)